# missing template Direct3D app in visual studio 2012

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, project-template

how to add missing template "Direct3D app" in visual studio 2012? There are many templates like this are missing and using online->templates result in no templates found. I later installed .net framwork 2 and 3.5 and when I tried latest version of .net 4.5 it says it is already installed on my OS windows 8. I have to download this template to start game development and would be very obliged for you help.

It is given as such on this website -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780569.aspx , its Visual C++, and many installed templates are missing. Only templates like win32 project, console, empty 2 test project templates and makefile project templates are shown. Rest there are no templates. Also, there is no category of Windows store in Visual C++,i.e. there are no project in Visual C++ of type windows store. Maybe I'm supposed to install something other than MSVC2012. Also, in 2010 default installed templates were hidden and you have to explicitly unhide them using "devenv.exe /vsshowtemplates" - the command was some thing like this. But there is no devenv.exe in MSVS2012 and there is not even a console window View->Other Windows. Please, if you can figure it out, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What language are you programming in, and what version of Visual Studio 2012 do you have?

In Visual Studio Express for Windows 8, you can find "Direct3D App" under Installed, Templates, Visual C++, Windows Store in the tree view control on the left-hand side in the "New Project" dialog.

You can install Visual Studio Express for Windows 8 from [here](http://aka.ms/JenVS2012), halfway down the page in blue.

Comment: Hi its C++ and you can read the question again. I have appended as much info as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the problem. Turns out one doesn't get templates like Grid App, Split App, Direct3D App, etc. when we install "Visual STudio 2012 for desktop". Instead we need to install "Visual STudio 2012 for Windows 8". Wasted 2 days in figuring this out. Microsoft should provide these info before providing tutorials such as on developing games.